# Dealing with no-List in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I´m dealing with this example of DataFrame **groupDisk**, is the result of a Grouping operation (by VM), I need to count how many **True** appears in the list of each row of the column Thin

```
    VM      Powerstate                        Thin
0   VIRTU1  [poweredOn]                       [False]
1   VIRTU2  [poweredOn, poweredOn]            [False, False]
2   VIRTU3  [poweredOn, poweredOn]            [False, False]
3   VIRTU4  [poweredOn, poweredOn]            [True, True]
4   VIRTU5  [poweredOn, poweredOn, poweredOn] [False, True, False]
```

This must be the result  = 3

The **Thin** column can be 1, 2 or N elements

Any clue will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `sum` if values are list of booleans:

```
df['new'] = df['Thin'].apply(sum)
print (df)
       VM                       Powerstate                  Thin  new
0  VIRTU1                      [poweredOn]               [False]    0
1  VIRTU2            [poweredOn,poweredOn]        [False, False]    0
2  VIRTU3            [poweredOn,poweredOn]        [False, False]    0
3  VIRTU4            [poweredOn,poweredOn]          [True, True]    2
4  VIRTU5  [poweredOn,poweredOn,poweredOn]  [False, True, False]    1
```

Or if values are strings use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Thin'].str.count('True')
print (df)
       VM                       Powerstate                Thin  new
0  VIRTU1                      [poweredOn]             [False]    0
1  VIRTU2            [poweredOn,poweredOn]       [False,False]    0
2  VIRTU3            [poweredOn,poweredOn]       [False,False]    0
3  VIRTU4            [poweredOn,poweredOn]         [True,True]    2
4  VIRTU5  [poweredOn,poweredOn,poweredOn]  [False,True,False]    1
```